# h5read crashes with large strings

Tags: r, hdf5

I have a `hdf5` file written using the `rhdf5` package. The output of `h5ls(myHDF5,all=TRUE)` is as follows:

```
  group      name       otype  dclass       dim
0     /     char5 H5I_DATASET  STRING   1867124
1     /     char6 H5I_DATASET  STRING   1867124
2     /     char7 H5I_DATASET  STRING   1867124
3     /      dims H5I_DATASET INTEGER         2
4     /   headers H5I_DATASET  STRING       212
5     /       int H5I_DATASET INTEGER 233390500
6     /  intorder H5I_DATASET INTEGER       125
7     /      real H5I_DATASET   FLOAT 156838416
8     / realorder H5I_DATASET INTEGER        84
```

If I read the `headers` object, which is a string vector, in the `myHDF5` file as follows: `headers<-h5read(myHDF5,"headers")`, it works fine.

But if I try to read a larger string vector as follows: `char5<-h5read(myHDF5,"char5")` then R crashes (`R Studio` reloads).

The larger string array `char5` had been previously stored as follows:

```
nr<-length(char5)
mxsize<-max(nchar(char5))  
h5createDataset(myHDF5,"char5",storage.mode="character",level=9,dims=nr,chunk=10000,size=mxsize)
h5write(char5,myHDF5,"char5)
```

while the smaller string array `headers` had been previously stored as follows:

```
nc<-length(headers)
mxsize<-max(nchar(headers))  
h5createDataset(myHDF5,"headers",storage.mode="character",level=9,dims=nc,chunk=nc,size=mxsize)
h5write(headers,myHDF5,"headers")
```

The main difference is the `chunk` size value used. I changed the `chunk` size for the larger string vector to be same the `dims`, i.e. `chunk=nr`, and R still crashes.

Why could be the reason for R to crash?

Note: R doesn't crash if I read the integer or float data from the `myHDF5` file.

Comment: What happens when you run R directly rather than via RStudio?

Comment: same thing unfortunately.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, sorry my bad about my previous comment. I ran R directly, via RScript and it runs fine (and I repeated it), but RStudio crashes everytime. Can you help?

Comment: In that case, post the problem to the RStudio forums.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, thanks. I just did that

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. A simple solution, although being not perfect is using the package "h5r":

```
library(h5r)

f <- H5File(h5FilePath)
g <- getH5Group(f, "/")
d <- getH5Dataset(g, "stringArray")[]
```